# How to split Excel row into multiple based on value in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to split the rows out in the first table based on comma separated values in Column C.

So columns A,B,D,E would be duplicated for each comma separated value in column C.

So the data would result in the table below.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Power Query

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithmic approach you can try

1. Get a reference to your data range
2. Loop over the rows in that range
3. Since you're going to be adding rows, loop bottom to top
4. For each row
5. `Split` the value in column C
6. If the resulting array has > 1 values, insert rows  for the new values
7. Copy Values into the new rows
8. Transpose the Split array into column C
9. Repeat